Powershell: Creating folders from filenames and moving files to to those folders
C:\Library contains 3 folders:
"P1", "P2", "P3"
C:\Library\P1 contains the file "T1 - P1"
C:\Library\P2 contains the files "T1 - P2", "T3 - P2"
C:\Library\P3 contains the files "T1-P3", "T2 - P3", "T3 - P3"
I want to end up with 3 new folders in C:\Library called "T1", "T2", and "T3" such that for k=1, 2, 3,
C:\Library\Tk contains all of the files of the form "Tk - Pj" where j=1 or  j=2 or j=3.
This is a simplification of some files I'm trying to organise, in reality the contents of each of the folders "Pk" is unknown and the indices run over ranges larger than 1, 2, 3.
I have some basic Python knowledge but have never used Powershell before beyond trying to figure out how to do this task by looking at posts on this site.
I would appreciate any help on how to proceed with this problem.
I have come up with the following process that should be repeated but am not sure how to implement it:

Select the first non-empty folder in C:\Library, suppose it is Pi

Select the first file in Pi, suppose it is Tj - Pi

Create a new folder in C:\Library with the name "Tj ".

Move all files in C:\Library of the form "Tj - Pk" to the folder "Tj".

Repeat steps 1-4 until all folders in C:\Library are empty.


I have tried using the cmdlet
Get-ChildItem

and perhaps I should combine it with -Recurse and -Depth
but I'm not sure this is the best approach.
I have looked at answers to similar questions but I'm not so sure on the syntax.

Welcome to SO, asdf. SO is a place where programmers help programmers make source code work. This question has no source code. Please take time to review the information at https://stackoverflow.com/help to understand how SO works. SO is not a free, bespoke coding service that is taking orders. Please copy and paste into the question the source code as text you are trying to make work. No pictures.

It might be simpler than it looks, but first could you post the code you have already tried and the results it gave? Coming from another language the logic might be sound but it fails because differences in how some things are managed

Try the following approach:

Discover all files in C:\Library\P*\*
For each file:

Test if the corresponding Tk folder exists, create it if not
Move the file



$basePath = "C:\Library"

# loop through each Pj folder
foreach ($pFolder in Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $basePath -Directory -Filter P*) {
  # loop through each Tk file
  foreach ($file in $pFolder |Get-ChildItem -File -Filter T*) {
    # extract the "Tk" part from the file name
    $targetFolderName = -split $file.Name |Select-Object -First 1
    # calculate destination path
    $targetPath = Join-Path -LiteralPath $basePath -ChildPath $targetFolderName

    # create target folder if it doesn't exist
    if (-not(Test-Path -LiteralPath $targetPath)) {
      New-Item -LiteralPath $targetPath -Type Directory |Out-Null
    }

    # move the file
    $file |Move-Item -Destination $targetPath
  }
}

